# Не одинаковы логические выражения попадания числа в интервал

Tags: javascript, математика, сравнение, операторы

Почему здесь в переменной if_2 выражения

```
(  this.x1 < point.x && point.x < this.x2  )
```

и

```
( this.x1 < point.x < this.x2 )
```

не являются одинаковыми?

Я хотел поменять для красоты кода на второе выражение, а проверка этой задачи отображает, что неверно, но ведь должно быть одинаковым?
Тоже самое и со вторым выражением, там хотел поэкспериментировать и сделал вместо

```
( this.x2 < point.x < this.x1 )
```

это:

```
( this.x2 < point.x && point.x < this.x1 )
```

и выводило, что неверно.

Можете объяснить разницу, пожалуйста, потому что я делал тесты и видел, что это работает одинаково.

```
// first IF-statement: (x-x1)/(x2-x1)=(y-y1)/(y2-y1);
// second IF-statement: x1 < x < x2 || x2 < x < x1;
class Segment
{
    constructor(p1, p2)
    {
        this.x1 = p1.x;
        this.y1 = p1.y;
        this.x2 = p2.x;
        this.y2 = p2.y;
    }
    contains(point)
    {
        let if_1 = (point.x - this.x1) / (this.x2 - this.x1) == (point.y - this.y1) / (this.y2 - this.y1);
        let if_2 = this.x1 < point.x && point.x < this.x2 || this.x2 < point.x < this.x1;
        return if_1 && if_2
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Все операторы выполняются строго по очереди. результат любого логического оператора, это логическое значение, true либо false. когда вы пишите `a < b < c` то сначала проверяется одно из условий, `a < b`, дает в результате например true. После этого происходит сравнение `true < c` ... А в случае `a < b && b < c` выполняется `a < b`, дает true, потом `a < b` дает, скажем то же true, и наконец выполняется `true && true`.

Comment: действительно ли выполняется `b < c` сначала? [These operators (&& and ||) exhibit "short-circuiting" behavior, which means that the second operand is evaluated only if needed.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Comment: @TimurVI конечно первое условие выполняется первым, запутался в буквах :)

Answer (score 2):

`(  this.x1 < point.x && point.x < this.x2  )` Это выражение означает, что point.x находится в интервале от x1 до x2. Вы думаете, что `( this.x1 < point.x < this.x2 )`  -это тоже интервал. Но это не совсем так. JS выполняет операторы сравнения по порядку. То есть сначала будет выполнено сравнение `this.x1 < point.x`. Его результат - логический. То есть это правда или ложь - true или false. И потом будет выполнена проверка такого вида: `true|false < this.x2`. True и false для арифметических операций приводятся к 1 и 0 соответственно. Не совсем то, что ожидаешь получить, когда пишешь проверку попадания x в интервал.

Answer (score 2):

`<` и `>` - операции сравнения. Результат их выполнения - логическое значение (boolean). Как  `point.x < this.x2` затем сравнить с `this.x1` (числом)?

В данном примере

```
(  this.x1 < point.x && point.x < this.x2  )
```

**сначала вычисляется выражение** `this.x1 < point.x`. **Если будет** `false`, **то дальше вычисление прекратится** и все выражение   `(  this.x1 < point.x && point.x < this.x2  )` вернет `false`.

Если после `this.x1 < point.x` будет `true` , то вычисляется правый операнд `point.x < this.x2`. Если `true` после него, то `true && true` будет true.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что,пример:

```
console.log(4 < 15 < 5);
```

В первом случае сравниваются два числа,результат true.Затем будут сравниваться два различных типа true и 5 ,а это численное преобразование и результат всего выражения будет неверным.Подробнее [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/types-conversion#%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)